# How can i fix "too many values to unpack" value error while file uploading in model serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm facing below issue in `ModelSerializer` file upload.

**Issue 1)** I'm trying to upload files using `ModelSerializer`. I have two models `BlogFilesSerializer` and `BlogSerializer`. when trying to upload a file it shows **`too many values to unpack error`** and I know its meaning why is this occurring but don't know how to handle these exceptions.

serializers.py

```
class BlogFilesSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    updated_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = BlogFilesModel
        fields = ('blog_files_id', 'blog', 'path',
                  'created_at', 'updated_at')


class BlogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    blog_files = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    uploaded_files = serializers.FileField(required=True, source='*')
    blog_created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_blog_files(self, obj):
        info = BlogFilesSerializer(BlogFilesModel.objects.filter(
            blog=obj).order_by('-pk'), many=True)

        if info.data:
            for i in info.data:
                user_detail = User.objects.get(pk=obj.user.id)
                i.__setitem__('user_detail', UserSerializer(user_detail).data)
                if i.get('user_detail'):
                    try:
                        del i['user_detail']['password']
                    except expression as identifier:
                        pass

        return info.data

    def get_blog_created_at(self, obj):
        formatted_date = obj.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        return formatted_date

    class Meta:
        model = BlogModel
        fields = ('blog_id', 'user', 'title', 'content',
                  'status',
                  'blog_files', 'blog_created_at',
                  'uploaded_files'
                  )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = BlogModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BlogModel.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'blog_id'
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,FileUploadParser)
```

models.py

```
class BlogModel(models.Model):

    BLOG_STATUS = (
        ('PUBLISH', 'Publish'),
        ('DRAFT', 'Draft'),
    )

    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=BLOG_STATUS)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'blogs'
        verbose_name = 'Blog'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Blogs'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def files(self):
        return 'something'


def blog_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/blogs/{}'.format(filename+str(datetime.now()))

class BlogFilesModel(models.Model):
    blog_files_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(
        BlogModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs',blank=True)
    path = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False,upload_to=blog_directory_path)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'blog_files'
        verbose_name = 'Blog'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Blogs'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.path)
```

**Issue 2)** i'm also unable to select multiple files for upload in `BlogSerializer` and in field `uploaded_files = serializers.FileField(required=True, source='*')` and their is no detailed explanation is DRF documentation. How can i add `multple` attribute to file field.

[image: Here is the image of element]
[image: Server Traceback error]

EDIT 1: I tried and got till here in `def to_internal_value(self, data):` the `field.source_attrs = []` their is no key so i'm getting this error. 
in my `ModelSerializer` i tried this  **`uploaded_files = serializers.FileField(required=True, source='files')`** added `files` as property to `BlogModel` now i'm getting **`'Error = files' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`** can someone guide me here.

Hope is have explained my problem well.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the actual error occurring in all of that code?

Comment: Where exactly are you unpacking ?

Comment: If you know the exact line of code you can use * to ignore the additional values. e.g. `a, b, *_ = (1, 3, 4, 5, 3,5)` 
This will only unpack first two values as a and b respectively.

Comment: This error occurs only when I upload the file. **exact line of code** i'm not sure.

Comment: @PavanWebbeez you have traceback of the error, you know what lead it there, and when it occur.

Comment: @vishes_shell i have tried to `.pop()` the field `uploaded_files` in `BlogSerializer.__init__()` and overide is but still the error persists.

Comment: @PavanWebbeez what you should do is to upload your traceback in question and probably include views.

Comment: @vishes_shell i have added the traceback image

Comment: @PavanWebbeez you should be uploading real traceback from your runserver. And not in image format, but in code.

Comment: @vishes_shell i have update image

Comment: remove **` source='*'`** from your filefield

Comment: You can try to use `blog_files = serializers.ArrayField(child=serializers.CharField())`

Comment: @JPG if i remove `source='*'` then im getting error **`Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `uploaded_files` on serializer `BlogSerializer`.`**

Comment: @vishes_shell `blog_files` is a `SerializerMethodField()` i use it to only display and to  **`uploaded_files = serializers.FileField(required=True)`** is used to get uploaded file. But `uploaded_files` file path is Uploaded to `BlogFilesModel`

Comment: @vishes_shell i have added additional information below in **EDIT 1** section. looking for guidance

Comment: @JPG i have added additional information below in EDIT 1 section. looking for guidance

Comment: @markwalker_ i have added additional information below in EDIT 1 section. looking for guidance